# PHP - Preserving character data when updating XML using DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom, cdata, preserve

I am reading an XML document into a DOM tree, then updating a node, and finally writing the tree into another XML file. The source XML file has below tag(I am not touching this tag in DOM) like

when using DOM->Save or SaveXML function, it is converting it to below

I want to preserve the original format as I am not touching this node in the update process. I've tried a few things and have been searching for a solution. It would be great if you can help figure out how to preserve the format of source XML when dumping DOM tree to a file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i believe you forgot put the example. :)